# ¿Cómo combinar tres objetos, en uno solo? en PHP

Tags: php, array, php5

Deseo combinar la información de tres objetos, de tal forma que se me una y me queden en un solo de esta forma:

```
$data1 = Array ([asunto] => ASOCIADOS S.A.S [numero-registro], 
[titulo] => proceso de registro [numero-registro],
[bodyHtml] => [contenido] [numero-registro]);

$data2 = Array ([bodyHtml] => Acta de Aprobación Oficial Cumplimiento [numero-registro]);

$data3 = Array ( [asunto] => [nombre] 20190917141519, 
[titulo] => proceso de registro 20190917141519,
[bodyHtml] => [contenido] 2019091714151);

$resultado = Array([asunto] => ASOCIADOS S.A.S 20190917141519
[titulo] = proceso de registro 20190917141519,
[bodyHtml] =  Acta de Aprobación Oficial Cumplimiento 20190917141519);
```

(como ayuda para entender los valores dentro de los corchetes son: [asunto] = ASOCIADOS S.A.S, [numero-registro] = 20190917141519, [contenido] = Acta de Aprobación Oficial Cumplimiento)

¿Cómo se puede realizar la combinación?, agradezco cualquier intento de ayuda.

Al intentar usar array_merge obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
$resultado = array_merge($data1, $data2, $data3);
print_r($resultado);

Array ([asunto] => [nombre] 20190917141519 
[titulo] => proceso de registro 20190917141519
[bodyHtml] => [contenido] 20190917141519)
```

Comment: Has intentado con `array_merge`? Por ejemplo `$resultado = array_merge($data1, $data2); print_r($resultado);`

Comment: Si intente usar array_merge con los tres pero no me dio, aunque leyendo la documentación con los 3 no creo que funcione, si lo hago con los dos funciona hasta cierto punto, ¿pero si luego quiero agregar el otro array como lo hago?

Comment: `array_merge` debería bastar, sería algo así: `$resultado=array_merge($data1, $data2, $data3);` Luego depura con `var_dump($resultado);` Si no te da el resultado esperado pulsa en [edit], mostrando lo que obtienes, lo que esperas obtener, qué problemas o errores hay, etc.

Comment: Ya agregue el resultado que me entrega php

Comment: También intente pasar los dos array una vez, y luego el tercero y me arrojo el mismo resultado, donde se plantea la pregunta.

Comment: En el código no usaste `array_merge`, aquí: `$resultado = array($data1, $data2, $data3);` Tampoco aparece clara la estructura de tus tres arrays, si son de varias dimensiones, etc. Sugiero que coloques en la pregunta el contenido real de tus arrays (en código funcional de PHP) para poder revisarlos y reproducir el problema.

Comment: Me disculpo fue un error lo de no colocar array_merge en la pregunta en e código, si estaba, y sobre las dimensiones de cada array, son iguales en todos, y están tal cual como en la pregunta.

Comment: Como está en la pregunta no son arrays válidos de PHP. Por ejemplo, el 1er array sería válido de esta forma: `$data1=array("asunto" => "ASOCIADOS S.A.S", "numero-registro" => 20190917141519, "contenido" => "Acta de Aprobación Oficial Cumplimiento");` y los mismo para  `$data2` y  para `$data3`. Si tú aplicas `array_merge` sobre tres arrays correctos debería darte un array con cada valor asociativo dentro de los tres. Otra cosa importante cuando se usa `array_merge` es saber si hay claves duplicadas en los diferentes arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El resultado que te devuelve array_merge() es correcto, ya que los tres arreglos asociativos tienen llaves en común, al hacer el merge va pisando el valor de la llave repetida, y por eso te muestra los valores del último arreglo.

Un opción es utilizar [array_merge_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge-recursive.php), aunque no se si es el resultado que quieres obtener.

De la documentación de [www.php.net](http://www.php.net):

array_merge_recursive() une los elementos de uno o más arrays de modo tal que los valores de uno sean añadidos al final del anterior. Devuelve el array resultante.

Si los arrays de entrada tienen las mismas claves de tipo string, los valores de estas claves son unidas en un array, y esto se realiza recursivamente, de modo que si uno de los valores es un array mismo, la función unirá también ésta con la correspondiente entrada de otro array. Sin embargo, si los arrays tienen la misma clave numérica, el valor posterior no sobrescribirá el valor original, sino que será añadido al final.

```
$resultado = array_merge_recursive($data1, $data2, $data3);
```

$resultado tendría el siguiente formato e información:

```
array ( 'asunto' => array ( 0 => 'ASOCIADOS S.A.S [numero-registro]', 1 => '[nombre] 20190917141519', ), 'titulo' => array ( 0 => 'proceso de registro [numero-registro]', 1 => 'proceso de registro 20190917141519', ), 'bodyHtml' => array ( 0 => '[contenido] [numero-registro]', 1 => 'Acta de Aprobación Oficial Cumplimiento [numero-registro]', 2 => '[contenido] 2019091714151', ), )
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono.

Comment: De nada Juan! Me alegro que te haya sido util.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes aplicar 2 veces `array_merge()` para que funcione, es decir, que una vez qu hayas hecho la primera unión, entonces el resultado lo vas a unir con el siguiente array, un ejemplo seria:

```
$array1 = [1 => 'Hola'];
$array2 = [2 => 'Como estas'];
$array3 = [3 => 'Que haces'];

$array4 = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$resultado = array_merge($array4, $array3);

print_r($resultado);
```

Y la salida de esta seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hola
    [1] => Como estas
    [2] => Que haces
)
```

Comment: Se pueden pasar las tres arrays a `array_merge`: **`$resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);`**